# The correct way to parse (localise) the price with currency code?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, price

I'm trying to find out one the correct way to localise the price with correct commas, whitespaces, points other separators positions and set right the currency code in correct place as postfix or prefix. Also I would like to work with negative numbers.

What I found?

I'm trying to google and try each solution, and the easiest way is:

```
private val format: DecimalFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(globalLocale) as DecimalFormat

fun format(amount: Double, currencyCode: String): String {
    format.currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode)
    return format.format(amount)
}
```

where `globalLocale` is `Locale.getDefault()` -> phone's locale.

The problem is with negative numbers, for some reasons it takes with brackets and calling `format(-10.00, "EUR")` returns `(EUR10.00)`

I found out one solution, to apply pattern:

`format.applyPattern("$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00")` but this hardcoding brakes currency sign position and whitespaces/commas/points localisation.

How to achieve this result ?

1. Pass `amount` and `currencyCode` and get correct `localised` price without any brackets in negative numbers?

**EDIT**
Seems this problem is only with Locale.US, so the question is how to avoid this parentheses in US locale?

Answer (score 0):

```
object Currency {
    fun format(num: Double, currency: String, maxFractionDigits: Int?): String {
        val format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault())
        format.maximumFractionDigits = maxFractionDigits ?: 0
        val cFormat = Currency.getInstance(currency)
        format.currency = cFormat
        return format.format(num)
    }
}




    val amountStr = Currency.format(
        budgetAllocationModel.used ?: 0.0,
        budgetAllocationModel.currency ?: "USD", 0
    )
```

Currency is an object that I use to covert the currency using Local.getDefault() to get the local string of the currency.

amountStr is an example using that object